# Change registered customer biliing email address on the time of checkout

Tags: orders, sales-order, billing-address, order-email, sales-quote

I am trying to implement one functionality where logged in user can able to change the billing email address on the time of checkout. I have tried to do that but all the time it updates customer account email address which I don't want. I have tried by updating email from quote & order both before save order function using `$quote->getCustomer->setEmail(",,,,,") & $order->getCustomer()->setEmail("...")` but unfortunately all the time it updates customer account email address but I need to update customer email id for particular order only (table- sales-flat-order).

Please suggest any solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used like `$order->setCustomerEmail('info@example.com');` in saveorder function before save order & it works for me

Answer (score 2):

`$quote->getCustomer()` retrieved the customer model. The email address for the order / quote is stored in the billing address object and in the quote object.

```
$quote->getBillingAddress()->setEmail('info@example.com');
$quote->setCustomerEmail('info@example.com');
```

Comment: unfortunately it didn't work for me..  all the time it's taking customer account email for order.

Comment: Updated my answer :)

Comment: hmm thats correct ...